# Java script files are not showing in debug mode in broweser in odoo 9

Tags: javascript, eclipse, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

Java script files are not showing in debug mode in browser in odoo 9

Hi,
 I try to debuy my own javascript in browser and unable to find that in the browser's js source list. I used to see all the js files in debug mode in both firefox and chrome browser earlier. Not sure what went wrong. Please find my environment details.

OS: Windows 8
IDE: Eclipse Mars, Eclipse Neon, Pycharm Community Edition 2017.2.1
Odoo build version : All versions 
Browsers Tried : Firefox, Chrome

And FYI i'm building from odoo source. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your URL showing the parameter **debug=assets** ?

Comment: Thanks Sudhansu. debug=assets gets me the js files. could you tell me what has changed in the meanwhile.I used to get the scripts by just giving debug=.  And kindly write the above comments as answer and i will approve it.

Comment: Thanks Anand. It will be nice of you.

I can only assume that the action bound to **Activate Developer Mode** may have been changed, because we see here that when we wrote in the URL, it worked.

Comment: Thanks Sudhanshu..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Dashboard**

Then in the right side you'll see a link saying "**Activate Developer Mode with assets**". Click on that and after that you can debug the JavaScript in the browser.

You can also try writing **'?debug=assets'** in your URL, just after the **web** word will allow you to enable the debug mode.

Your URL now will be something like this

```
http://localhost:8069/web?debug=assets#menu_id=78&action=87&active_id=channel_inbox
```